# Material-UI Autocomplete features don't seem to be working for me

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Material-UI Autocomplete control and really like it, however I am not even using some of it's coolest features (autoComplete, autoSelect, autoHighlight).  When I enabled these, the behavior doesn't seem to change.  Interestingly, I see the same thing when I try them in the "Playground" section on the following website https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/.  I've tried this website with multiple browsers and multiple computers, and those features just don't seem to be working.

For instance..."autoComplete" has the following description..

> If *true*, the portion of the selected suggestion that has not been
>   typed by the user, known as the completion string, appears inline
>   after the input cursor in the textbox. The inline completion string is
>   visually highlighted and has a selected state.

However I never see the "completion string" following the input cursor.  Similarily, "autoSelect" does not select the current suggestion when the control loses focus (e.g. TAB key is pressed).

I believe I have the latest versions of the material-ui components installed...

```
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10"
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1"
  "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49"
```

Am I misunderstanding these features?  I certainly believe I could be doing something wrong, but that wouldn't explain why they don't seem to work on the material-ui website in their own "playground".

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Please create a working example (you can use https://codesandbox.io for that).

Comment: @Dekel The "Playground" has working examples that include code.  They don't work for me on the "Playground" or in my own code.  I know this seems counter intuitive, but I guess what I am asking is "do the Playground samples NOT work for others, or is it just me"? From their Playground you can launch it into codesandbox and the issue exists there too.  For example... https://codesandbox.io/s/ck1fu.  Is that more clear?

Comment: To reproduce, launch the codesandbox...access the "autoComplete" control.  Start typing "The God".  As I understand the intended behavior, it should be showing "father" after my cursor as the suggested auto completion (presumably in a lighter font color).

Similarly, you access the "autoSelect" control and start typing "The God" and then force the control to lose focus (e.g. hit TAB). The expected behavior is that "The Godfather" is automatically selected since it was the first suggestion in the list.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the playground in the materil-ui.com website.

Comment: @Dekel... So when you try my use cases as I have described them, you see the "expected" behavior NOT the behavior that I am observing?  You are seeing the auto completion of the movie titles and the auto select on incomplete matches?  What could explain it working for you in the codesandbox, but not for me?

Comment: Hi @DanH. 
You are right, the inline text autocompletion is not working as expected. Have you found a solution to this problem yet? `autoHighlight` works, but `autoComplete` and `autoSelect` does not seem to work for me either.